# Is there a KVM solution where I can view and control multiple devices on a running computer?

Tags: vnc, remote-access, kvm-switch

I am looking for a Keyboard Video Mouse control to control multiple computers. Instead of the traditional way of time multiplexing a real monitor / keyb / mouse, I would like to see all the screens as windows on any computer - like VNC or a remote login.

Unlike VNC, I would also be able to solve boot problems.

Do any such solution exist? what are they?

Comment: As the oerating system is not running at boot time, no software installed in the operating system will allow you interact with BIOS. You will need some hardware based solutions, however they are only available on professional server computers.

Answer (score 1):

There are hardware solutions from several manufacturers, google for [kvm over ip](https://www.google.fr/search?q=kvm+over+ip).  They convert the vga video signal into digital and you can access the screen, keyboard, and mouse from a java-enabled browser. Many users can access the same screen, and you can set up access restrictions and so on.

The box doing all the work usually runs an embedded Linux (and is not hackable). Extra features can be emulating a cdrom or memory stick on the usb so you can get the bios to boot from an image you sent over the network.

Prices are from about $200 I imagine.

Answer (score 1):

If your computers are running from an Intel core processor that supports vPro then you can use Intels AMT (Active Management Technology).

If your running AMD then DASH (Desktop and mobile Architecture for System Hardware) might work for you.

It all depends on what kind of hardware you have on the computers you want to remote control.

To research this further look into "kvm over ip" and "out-of-band management" and see what hardware you need for this.